# Where is the Constraint kind defined?

Tags: haskell, ghc, constraint-kinds

I'm not familiar with GHC internals but I have a couple questions about ConstraintKinds.

It says from [`GHC.Exts`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html) that

```
data Constraint :: BOX
```

which is misleading because `Constraint` is a kind of sort `BOX`.  This brings us to the first question: we can import and export kinds?  How does that work?

Please correct me on this next part if I'm totally off. From trying out different imports and glancing around at the source on hackage, my guess is that `GHC.Exts` imports `Constraint` from `GHC.Base`, who in turn, imports it from `GHC.Prim`. But I do not see where it is defined in [`GHC.Prim`](http://git.haskell.org/packages/ghc-prim.git)?

Comment: `GHC.Prim` is purely fictitious anyway. Based on comments in `GHC.Base`, it seems its interface was once defined in `GHC.Prim.hi-boot`, but that file doesn't seem to exist anywhere any more.

Comment: I found an [older version](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Prim.html) of it. But like you said, this is not the case anymore in current HEAD.

Comment: That "older version" you found is actually recent, and just as fake. As the comments indicate, it is only used by Haddock, and never actually compiled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no definition of `Constraint` in any Haskell source file. It's a built-in, wired-in name that is defined to belong within `GHC.Prim` in the GHC sources itself. So in particular `Constraint` is not a promoted datatype, there's no corresponding datatype of kind `*` that is called `Constraint`.

There are other kinds in GHC that are treated similarly, such as `AnyK`, `OpenKind` or even `BOX` itself.

GHC doesn't really make a big difference internally between datatypes and kinds and anything above. That's why they e.g. all show up as being defined using `data` albeit with different target kinds.

Note that as far as GHC is concerned, we also have

```
data BOX :: BOX
```

It's impossible for a user to directly define new "kinds" of super-kind `BOX`, though.

As far as I know, importing / exporting also makes no difference between the type and kind namespaces. So e.g.

```
import GHC.Exts (OpenKind, BOX, Constraint)
```

is legal. In fact, if you then say

```
x :: Constraint
x = undefined
```

you don't get a scope error, but a kind error, saying that a type of kind `*` is expected, but a type/kind of kind `BOX` is provided.

I should perhaps also say that the whole story about kinds is somewhat in flux, and there are proposals being discussed that change this a bit: see e.g. https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/NoSubKinds for related discussion.

Comment: We actually discovered a subtle difference the other day, which is perhaps a bug: If you try to *reexport* with `module ... (module GHC.Exts)` or `(module GHC.Prim)`, the `Constraìnt` kind will be mysteriously excluded. You have to name it explicitly in export lists, as `GHC.Exts` does itself. (BTW you can actually `:i (GHC.Prim.*)`, although it seems impossible to actually *use* `*` that way.)